# Extracting a specific length substring using SED

Tags: unix, sed

I have the following SED command

```
echo "abcd_2222222233333333_jdkj" | sed -e 's/^\(.*\)_\(.*\)_\(.*\)$/\2_\1_\3/'
```

that returns

2222222233333333_abcd_jdkj

That's great, but I really want

22222222-33333333_abcd_jdkj

Is this possible with an easy tweak or do I need some non-sed solution?  Basically, I know the number is 16 bytes, but I need to break it into two 8 byte numbers.

Comment: Do you have a good reason to use `sed` for this in the first place, instead of bash's built-in regex capabilities?

Comment: ...that said, `*` means `{0,}` ("match zero-or-more of the preceding thing"); but you can always write `{8}` ("match exactly eight of the preceding thing") instead.

Comment: Also, which `sed`? Is this GNU (as on Linux) or BSD (as on MacOS)?

Comment: Thanks!!  @CharlesDuffy That worked.  Total unix amateur here!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.*` to match any number of characters, you can use `.{8}` to match exactly eight characters.

The below also uses `sed -r` to allow ERE syntax, which requires fewer backslashes and is generally easier to read than the default BRE. (On systems with BSD-style tools, this might be `sed -E` instead).

```
sed -re 's/^(.*)_(.{8})(.*)_(.*)$/\2-\3_\1_\4/' <<<"abcd_2222222233333333_jdkj"
```

By the way -- I would strongly suggest using `[^_]*` instead of `.*` so your regex can't match underscores where you don't want it to. (`.` means "any character"; `[^_]` means "any character except `_`"). That's not just a correctness enhancement -- it can also make your regex faster to evaluate by avoiding backtracking (where the regex engine realizes it's matched too much content and needs to undo some of its prior matches).

---

Also consider bash's built-in regex support:

```
string='abcd_2222222233333333_jdkj'
re='([^_]+)_([[:digit:]]{8})([[:digit:]]+)_(.*)'

if [[ $string =~ $re ]]; then
  result=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}-${BASH_REMATCH[3]}_${BASH_REMATCH[1]}_${BASH_REMATCH[4]}
  echo "Result is: $result"
else
  echo "No match found"
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution per the above commenter's tip works

```
echo "abcd_2222222233333333_jdkj" | sed -e 's/^\(.*\)_\(.\{8\}\)\(.\{8\}\)_\(.*\)$/\2-\3_\1_\4/'
```

Comment: I did write an answer, not just comments. :)

Comment: (...if you can't see it, perhaps try refreshing the page?)